# how can i get QQMail Starred folder with java mail

Tags: java, email, qq

i have try this `val f = store.defaultFolder.list("*")`
but just get :
INBOX,
Sent Messages,
Drafts,
Deleted Messages,
Junk,

how to access QQMail or other Mail "Starred" folder

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear what you want to achieve. Have a look here => [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"starred" is not a folder is a flag , and i get it by this line code `message.flags.systemFlags.contains(Flags.Flag.FLAGGED)`
if get true means this message belong to "starred folder"